# Dataframe customisation using the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like below

[image]

I would like to convert this to following dataframe by adding headers and also put the value on last column as header as follows

[image]

Any help on this would be appreciated, i tried `.groupby` but it requires a column name which i dont have now.

Comment: What are the current columns, 0, 1, 2?

Comment: Yes you are right, its 0,1,2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pandas.pivot_table`

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

# ... your data in df

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO('''date value data
01/01/2019 30 data1
01/01/2019 40 data2
02/01/2019 20 data1
02/01/2019 10 data2'''), sep=' ')

results = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['date'],
                     columns=['data'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)

print(results)
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: this is duplicate question. You shouldn't show images in your answer

Comment: Oh! I did not know. Do you know why I shouldn’t not show images?

Comment: I think that an image (cut) in which the code you have already shown is partially seen is redundant and unnecessary, just show the output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel this worked, thanks for your effort

Comment: Windowws you are welcome. @ansev, I have cropped out redundancy:) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'X':['01/01/2009','01/01/2009','02/01/2009','02/01/2009'],
                'Y':[20,30,40,25],
                'data':['Data1','Data2','Data1','Data2']})
df.pivot(index='X',columns='data',values='Y')
df.columns = ['Date' , 'Data1' , 'Data2']
df
```

code snippet

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method using [DataFrame.stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    0: ['01-01-2009', '01-01-2009', '02-01-2009', '02-01-2009'],
    1: [20, 30, 40, 25],
    2: ['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data1', 'Data2']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
renamed = df.rename(columns={0: 'date', 1: 'values', 2: 'source'})
new_index = renamed.set_index(['date', 'source'])
result = new_index.unstack(1)['values']
```